# Generating a unique ID

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I was looking into functions that generate unique IDs - my specific requirement is that the unique ID would need to be 8 digits only.

Anyway I've just realised we can set an ID auto increment field to start from any number. So suppose I have it start from 11111111 - am I right in thinking that all new records will increment from this value? If so then I have my unique 8 digit ID and no need to use a function for this.

And also if a record is deleted then will a new record re-use that deleted ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Autoincrement-Values are not reused

2) Yes, by setting the autoincrement counter to an 8-digit number (e.g. 10000000), you can achieve this! (Table option "AUTO_INCREMENT = N")

Comment: Cheers mate. Are there any concerns in using this approach? For example the ID value is being exposed on the front end - is that a problem?

Comment: @GSTAR, what concerns would you have?  Whether or not your user knowing the ID is a problem depends on what you are doing with it.  I'd say if a user knows an ID and can get access to something they shouldn't, you have far bigger problems.  Remember, these are generated sequentially.

Answer (score 6):

That is correct.  If your auto-number columns start at 11111111, then your next row will have the number 11111112.

When a record is deleted, its auto-number is *not* reused.

**Edit:** Regarding maximum values, that is dependent on the column type you have chosen.  From the MySQL documentation:

> Use a large enough integer data type for the AUTO_INCREMENT column to hold the maximum sequence value you will need. When the column reaches the upper limit of the data type, the next attempt to generate a sequence number fails. For example, if you use TINYINT, the maximum permissible sequence number is 127. For TINYINT UNSIGNED, the maximum is 255.

You could use an INT and go up to 4294967295, or BIGINT and go up to 18446744073709551615.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Also note that when the column gets to 99999999 the next insertion will get an error, auto-increment will not wrap around and go back to 00000001.

Comment: @tloach - won't it just go to the next value, i.e. 100000000 ?

Comment: @tloach, you are correct in that it won't wrap around on the maximum value, but incorrect in that 99999999 is the maximum value.  I have added clarification, with references to the MySQL documentation.

Comment: I assumed he had defined to column to hold 8-digit numbers only (INT(8))